# Why can't an Action<Object> delegate be used as a WaitCallback for Threadpool?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, threadpool

The delegates `WaitCallback` and `Action<Object>` share the same signature. Still, as the code below proves, they cannot be regarded as the same type.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WaitCallback wcb = (o) => Console.WriteLine("Hello from wcb delegate");
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(wcb);//works

    Action<object> action = (o) => Console.WriteLine("Hello from action<object> delegate");
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(action);//does not compile: Cannot convert from Action<object> to WaitCallback  

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have two questions about this observation:

1. Why is it so that delegates with the same signature but a different name are not regarded as the same type? Could the language design team have chosen differently or would that have led to inconsistencies or other problems?
2. When the `Action` delegates where introduced in the .NET framework 2.0, `WaitCallback` already existed. I wonder if that were not the case, would there have been a justification for introducing the extra delegate type `WaitCallback` in stead of using `Action`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the type system's point of view `WaitCallback` is a different type from `Action<object>` and there exists no implicit conversion between them. So you cannot use an `Action<object>` where a `WaitCallback` is expected. Actual *methods* referenced and used as delegates, however, only care about compatibility of their argument list and return type, so instead of having an anonymous method you could have

```
private void Foo(object o) {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from actual method");
}
```

and the following lines would work without a problem:

```
WaitCallback wcb = Foo;
Action<object> action = Foo;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo);
```

Note that in this case the method's *name* is used to refer to it, which is parsed and handled completely different than passing a variable of a certain type to a method. For the latter you're entirely at the mercy of the actual types and their conversions and delegates are in no way special.

The specification also contains the following note:

> Delegate types in C# are name equivalent, not structurally equivalent. Specifically, two different delegate types that have the same parameter lists and return type are considered different delegate types.

*(Warning: speculation; I wasn't on the language design team)* So this was a conscious choice and considering what I wrote above, it may not have been impossible to allow what you requested, but it'd be a major exception to how overload resolution works. So I guess that call was made in order to simplify the language. Furthermore, back in the C# 1 days, there probably weren't that many delegates that were actually structurally compatible.

As for your second point, they would probably have gone with `Action` in that case. As an example, see the [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which takes an `Action` instead of a custom delegate. For actions that take no or one parameter that seems a fairly obvious case not to introduce a new delegate type. However, for things like `Action<string, string, int, double>` or equivalent `Func` types I guess having an actual named type that can be documented will be far better than using the generic `Action` or `Func` types.

Comment: Thanks Joey for your elaborate answer. Your way of phrasing it gave me more insight in how delegates work. Your explanation of method names referred to as delegates is a nice bonus.